# In Wikidata SPARQL, how can I return other fields?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

In my Wikidata query, I actually have 2 problems.

1. Date of Birth + Gender + Description is not returned
2. GROUP BY does not aggregate based on the name (Bad Aggregate Error)

```
SELECT ?person ?label ?dob ?gender ?description
WHERE
{
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
          rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER(STRSTARTS(?label, "Michael Bloom")).
}
GROUP BY ?person ?label
LIMIT 5
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3Flabel%20%3Fdob%20%3Fgender%20%3Fdescription%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%20FILTER%28STRSTARTS%28%3Flabel%2C%20%22Michael%20Bloom%22%29%29.%0A%7D%0A%23GROUP%20BY%20%3Fperson%20%3Flabel%0ALIMIT%205)

Comment: As an alternative to the answer below, you can use the entity service to search for entities by string more efficient than with SPARQL `STRSTARTS` function

Comment: `SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?dob ?gender ?personDescription WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "Michael Bloom" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .
      ?person wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .      
  }
  ?person wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q5
   OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P569 ?dob }
   OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P21 ?gender }
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must query all fields for them to being returned (`SPARQL` can't guess where to get them), with the exception of labels and descriptions when using Wikibase Label Service.
2. All fields in your `SELECT` must be in the `GROUP BY` clause, with the exception of the use of the `GROUP_CONCAT` function that will concatenate all values into one field.
3. Bad news: searching humans by other than their exact label in Wikidata Query Service is hard, as you will often hit the timeout of 60 seconds. A solution, as shown by AKSW, is to use Wikibase Mediawiki API and do an entity search.

Here is an example of your query rewritten:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?dob ; SEPARATOR = ' / ') AS ?dob) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gender ; SEPARATOR = ' / ') AS ?gender)
WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "Michael Bloom" .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .
    ?person wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
  }
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P569 ?dob }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P21 ?gender }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription
```

Comment: Thanks Querybook! This works very well (and seems to be fast).  How can I get the image and place of birth (in both text + lat/long) as well?